# Sending photos via Telegram using multipart/form-data POST

Tags: image, http, base64, telegram, multipartform-data

I would like to know how to send a photo via Telegram using a multipart/form-data POST.
To make the POST requests, I am using the Firefox extension [REST Client APIsHub](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/rest-client-apishub).

As a test, I have been able to use it to receive messages using the /getUpdates URL.

Since I am new to HTTP, I am struggling to understand exactly how to send photos. Should I be encoding the photo into a multipart/form, or into a URL. Or both? And is my problem coming from my misunderstanding of HTTP, or of Telegram?

This is what I have tried so far. According to the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto), photos should be sent using multipart/form-data. I have looked around, and can't find a clear working example of a multipart/form-data that I can copy to sanity check. However, I have pieced together this. It contains a tiny PNG image of a white square, outlined in red, encoded in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

[image: Tiny image]

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="chat_id";
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

12******90

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="pic01.png"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAIAAABLbSncAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAJOgAACToAYJjBRwAAAAZSURBVBhXY3gro4IVgST+Y4DBIIEFyagAAPvujIG0bdZ8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Currently, I am receiving a 400 "Bad Request: there is no photo in the request".

Questions:

1. To send this photo, should I put something in the "headers" section?
2. How should the photo be encoded? Is Base64 correct, or should the encoding be something else?
3. Is the content of the body correct?